# C++17 how to test class has a member variable?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I am going down the route

```
struct S {
  static constexpr int extra=5;
};

struct V {
};


template <typename T>
void f()
{  
  if (std::is_same_v<decltype(T::extra), int>)
    std::cout<< "extra exists" <<std::endl;
}
```

but calling `f<S>()` fails as

```
std::is_same_v<decltype(S::extra), int> == 0
```

and `f<V>()` does not compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are stuck in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), there is some infrastructure that you can add to make detection like this much easier.

### Detection-idiom

The most reusable/consistent way to detect features like this is via the [Detection idiom](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrock/blog/detection_idiom.php), which leverages SFINAE through [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) in a template.

This can be taken verbatim from [`std::experimental::is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)'s page from cppreference. This effectively offers C++17 the ability to detect features in a way that is similiar to C++20's concepts; and the infrastructure can be reused easily for just about any detection.

The basics of what you would need are:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid,
          template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector {
  using value_t = std::false_type;
  using type = Default;
};
 
template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector<Default, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
  using value_t = std::true_type;
  using type = Op<Args...>;
};
 
} // namespace detail
 
struct nonesuch{};

template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;
```

<sup>**Note:** The above infrastructure can be reused for *any* detection. It is a very useful reusable tool in C++17.</sup>

With `is_detected`, all you need is a *detector*, which is simply a template alias that evaluates to a `decltype` expression of something that may, or may not, exist.

So in your case, to conditionally detect the presence of `T::extra`, you can do this with a simple detector like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using detect_extra = decltype(T::extra);
```

Putting it all together now, you can use this detector to conditionally toggle the branch:

```cpp
if constexpr (is_detected<detect_extra,T>::value) {
    // Only do code if 'T' has 'T::extra' (e.g. 'S')
} else {
    // Only do code if 'T' does not have 'T::extra' (e.g. 'V')
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qan761)</kbd>

---

If equivalent conversion to a specific type is important, such as `extra` needing to be convertible to `int`, you can also use `is_detected_convertible`  and use the detector to check for if the result can be convertible to the desired type. Using the same cppreference page again, you can define `is_detected_convertible` as:

```cpp
template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using detected_t = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::type;

template <class To, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected_convertible = std::is_convertible<detected_t<Op, Args...>, To>;
```

Which allows the check to instead be:

```cpp
if constexpr (is_detected_convertible<int, detect_extra, T>::value) {
    // Only do code if 'T' has 'T::extra' convertible to int (e.g. 'S')
} else {
    // Only do code if 'T' does not have 'T::extra', or is not int
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8cTcqK)</kbd>

### Concepts (C++20+ only)

If you have access to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) and beyond, `concept`s make this much simpler -- since you can simply use a `concept` + `requires` clause like:

```cpp
#include <concepts> // std::same_as

template <typename T>
concept HasExtra = requires(T) {
  {T::extra} -> std::same_as<int>;
};

if constexpr (HasExtra<T>) {
    // Only do code if 'T' has 'T::extra' and is 'int' (e.g. 'S')
} else {
    // Only do code if 'T' does not have 'T::extra' (e.g. 'V')
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sdxKao)</kbd>

Comment: Your `C++20` solution does not work because expression concept checks use `decltype((e))` rather than `decltype(e)`. This results in `decltype((T::extra))` being of type `int const&` when feeding in type `S`, which does not satisfy the return-type-requirement of `std::same_as<int>`.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that `decltype(T::extra)` (when `T` is `S`) is `int const` (is `constexpr` so is also `const`), not `int`. This explain why `f<S>()` fails.

To test if a class has a member variable there are many ways, I suppose.

A possible solution is develop something as

```
void type_extra (...);

template <typename T>
auto type_extra (T t) -> decltype(t.extra);

template <typename T>
using type_extra_t = decltype(type_extra(std::declval<T>()));
```

Now you can write `f()` as follows

```
template <typename T>
void f()
{  
  if ( not std::is_same_v<type_extra_t<T>, void> )
   {
     std::cout<< "extra exists" <<std::endl;

     if ( std::is_same_v<type_extra_t<T>, int> )
        std::cout<< "(and is int)" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Observe that now the `type_extra_t<S>` is `int`, not `int const`; this way (getting the type from the returned type of a function) loose the constness of the variable.

If you want maintain the constness, you can return a reference from the function (so it return a `int const &` in the `S` case)

```
template <typename T>
auto type_extra (T t) -> decltype(t.extra) &;
```

and remove the reference from the using (so, in the `S` case, `int const &` become `int const`)

```
template <typename T>
using type_extra_t
   = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(type_extra(std::declval<T>()))>;
```

Comment: Interesting. Having the same idea, I tried my luck with `std::remove_cv<decltype(T::extra)>` but this didn't work. Maybe, I oversaw something... [**My try on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1cfd7543e9c2ca8) ... while your approach seems to work fine: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc844f02a7c19948)

Comment: Was not aware C++ had the alternative token `not`, makes conditional expr so much easier to read

Comment: @Scheff - You have to use `typename std::remove_cv<...>::type` (or `std::remove_cv_t<...>`), not simply `std::remove_cv<...>` (you have to extract the internal `type`)

Comment: @M.A - I'm agree: I find very difficult to read a `! condition`.

Comment: I somehow was expecting hat I oversaw something stupid... Now, it works: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a62499c3eb0f9695). Thanks for the enlightment.

Comment: @Scheff - Nobody is perfect. I've done your exact error zillions of times.